# Is it possible to use Windows Update to update a program?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-update

As we know we can set an address so Windows downloads its updates from specific address.

I want to make update files and put them on that specific address on a server and computers on network download updates from that address and install updates.

The question is that:

1. Is it possible to manipulate other programs files and settings (except Microsoft applications) using Windows Update?
2. If yes, how to make a Windows Update package ?

Comment: I think your question is offtopic. If it's related to server administration (i.e. configuring the *location* of updates) then it's better on a server forum, but if it's related to having "YourApp" in the list of windows updates, then I think the answer is "there seems to be a way if you've written a driver and probably gone through a certification process, but for the every-day-man, certainly not".

Comment: @Noon: asking a way to make update packages and hacking through windows update is offtopic?

Comment: @HPT: That's what I just said, wasn't it?

Comment: @Noon: so asking a way to make bmp file is offtopic too?!

Comment: @HPT: I don't know where this bizarre series of questions is going but it seems to be founded on a strange assmuption; anyway, I leave you to it :)

Comment: I don't know why people are voting to close this as "off topic". It certainly doesn't belong on ServerFault.

Comment: @cody: I especially nead it in windows xp because updates in windows xp are in `msi` or `exe` files, but in vista and 7 they are `msu` files and the mechanism has changed.

Comment: @HPT: You are only deploying your software on Windows XP? I removed the tag because I don't think this is a Windows XP-specific question. I think that's information that's better included in the question itself, rather than something we're supposed to glean from the tags. But whatever.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. Windows Update and Microsoft Update are mechanisms only available to Microsoft. It would make sense for them (and customers) to open them up for other vendors, but nobody announced anything in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a domain controller, you can distribute updates of your application via group policy. [look here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737461(v=ws.10).aspx)

Another option: write a client application for distribution your application updates.

And one more option : Microsoft System Center $)